Error trying to upload an image to Dataverse
In Power Apps, I'm sending an image to Power Automate, since I want to upload it into Dataverse:
The image is being sent with:
JSON(UploadedImage1.Image,JSONFormat.IncludeBinaryData)

On Power Automate:

Is generating the error below on step "Compose":
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose' inputs at
line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function
'base64ToBinary' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The
value cannot be decoded from base64 representation.'.

This is the code in Compose:
base64ToBinary(outputs('Compose_2'))

This is the output of Compose_2:
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4f+8RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAANAA8BAgAJAAAAqgAAABABAgAGAAAAtAAAABIBAwABAAAACAAAABoBBQABAAAAugAAABsBBQABAAAAwgAAACgBAwABAAAAAgAAADEBAgAdAAAAygAAADIBAgAUAAAA6AAAADsBAgAAAQAA/AAAABMCAwABAAAAAgAAAJiCAgAAAgAA/AEAAGmHBAABAAAAZgQAAKXEBwBqAAAA/AMAAH4LAABGVUpJRklM


Have your trimmed your data properly, output compose_2, as before applying your need to remove data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/ string along with the quotes " from front and last.

Pass the contentBytes to the base64ToBinary function to resolve the issue:

